# Ignore synchronization for $timeout but not $http in Protractor Tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Protractor ‘synchronizes’ with Angular as to allow me to write synchronous looking tests. This means that Protractor will wait until Angular is done with any `$http` or `$timeout` functions before continuing. Unfortunately I am using recursive `$timeout` calls throughout the codebase which is a very reasonable thing to do, though it prevents Protractor from ever fully synchronizing with Angular. I can turn this synchronization off though it would force the tests to explicitly wait for every async action, which is most every action. I could move the recursive `$timeout` calls to `$interval` but it would make the production code clunkier.

Ideally I would prefer to not explicitly wait for every `$http` in tests while still being able to use `$timeout` recursively in production code.

Is it possible to ignore synchronization for `$timeout` but not `$http` in Protractor Tests?

Comment: Can you use the `$interval` service instead of `$timeout`?  That should give you the same behavior without breaking Protractor: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Comment: I could move the recursive $timeout calls to $interval but it would make the production code clunkier.